# Reg Ex for validating phone number

Tags: regex

I want to create a regular expression for validating phone numbers.

For example:
+381 493 34949499

+381 - 1-4 numbers
493 - 2-3 numbers
34949499 - 5-15 numbers

```
'/^\+\d{3} \(\d{2,3}\) \d{5,16}$/')
```

I trid something like this but I got an error in +381 (country code).

Comment: Remove all non-digits, check the number of digits and reformat it any way you want.

Answer (score 0):

Better use a proper module, [perl](/questions/tagged/perl) have [Number::Phone](https://metacpan.org/pod/Number::Phone) module to validate phone numbers.

Answer (score 0):

Probably you should not build that yourself, as there is a huge amount of different writing styles for phone numbers and I myself often get annoyed by services which implemented that stuff by theirselves. See 
[here (Wikipedia)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/National_conventions_for_writing_telephone_numbers)
and check out some people who already put some work in there:
[Regexlib](http://regexlib.com/Search.aspx?k=phone%20number&AspxAutoDetectCookieSupport=1).
To have some general advice: I would rather use \b as word boundaries instead of ^ and $ which are line boundaries. Probably you would want to use a tool like [Regexr](http://www.regexr.com) or  [Rubular](http://rubular.com) to test your regular expressions first. Regexr also coems with examples for different stuff.